# tableview deleting rows issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, row, delete-row

I´m having a problem when trying to delete the right row in my view. I have a tableview with 3 dynamic created cells grouped, and also, i´m using the editing mode. Everything is working fine when adding more rows in each section and also deleting them, but when i try to delete a specific row, it always delete the last one. Let´s say that i have added rows 1,2,3 (besides de original one) and i want to delete number 2, it always deletes number 3. I have also a method that gives automatically a tag for each new row created.. how can i pass the deleting problem? any ideas? i know i have to identify somehow the tag of the deleted row in order for this to work...Each section has one row, 100 then 200 and 300... this is my code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)TableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
     int i=0;
     for (i=0; i<myarray.count; i++)
     {
        UITableViewCell *aux=[myarray objectAtIndex:i];

        if (aux.tag >= 101 && aux.tag < 200 && indexPath.section==0) {
            [myarray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [Table reloadData];
        }
        if (aux.tag >= 201 && aux.tag < 300 && indexPath.section==1) {
            [myarray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [Table reloadData];
        }
        if (aux.tag >= 301 && indexPath.section==2) {
            [myarray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [Table reloadData];
        }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this method and replace it with yours:

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)TableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {

   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
   {
      [myarray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        [Table reloadData];
   }
 }
```

Comment: It didn´t work and i need that method in order to distinguish between the first row tag 100 (that is also the 0 section) and second row tag 200 (that is also the 1 section) and third row tag 300 (that is also the 2 section).So the idea is, if my aux is equal to the deleted row, then, delete it from the array and also tableview...but i don´t know how to do this!!...and i<myarray.count is very useful because before editing(and add new rows) i have the original ones, and they must not be deleted...More ideas?!.Thanks.